Alternate Proof for Sum of Sides of a Triangle Inequality
I recently stumbled upon an idea for a  proof for the sum of two sides of a triangle inequality.
Note that I am just a high school student and feel free to correct me wherever if I am wrong.
Statement/Theorem : The sum of the two sides of a triangle will always be greater than the other side.
Proof:
Let us take a line segment $AB$ and assume it to be the largest side of a Triangle.
We need to prove that the sum of the other two sides will always be greater than $AB$.
Let us now take an arbitrary point on $AB$ and assume it divides $AB$ into two segments of length $a$ and $b$. Let $a$ and $b$ be the distance of the 3rd Vertex(Point $C$) of the triangle from the points $A$ and $B$ respectively.
The locus  of the third vertex describes a circle of radius $a$ with Point $A$ as the center and respectively for Point $B$ a circle of radius $b$.
Note that the circles touch at only one point which lies on the line $AB$.
Now, we are clearly able to see that both of the radii cannot reach out to touch each other without atleast one of them extending themselves.
That extra portion of length lying outside the circle is the length which makes the sum of two sides of the triangle always greater than the 3rd side.
This also simultaneously that difference between any 2 sides is always lesser than the third side.
I hope this proof is valid and please verify for me.
I am truly sorry for not being able to paste the image for the proof.

It's a good idea, but is applied the wrong way around or is missing a step.
With your construction of line segment $AB$ and two circles, you have proved $AC+BC > AB$ if $C$ is outside of both those two circles. But it doesn't prove the statement if $AC < a$ or $BC < b$. A different choice of $a$ and $b$ would, but you said that choice was arbitrary.
To make the proof more correct, start with a given triangle and do a construction based on it.
(Or, show that among the possible constructions with different values of $a$ and $b$, every triangle is congruent to at least one such construction. But that amounts to the same thing, with more confusing phrasing.)

Proof is valid.
Some tweaks you might want to consider.
(1) You have to cover all cases. You have covered the case $AB$ is largest to show that $AB < (BC+CA)$
It is necessary , though trivial , to show that that this holds even when $AB$ is smallest , or when $AB$ is middle , or when $AB=BC>CA$ (2 large sides)
(2) You are considering the case when Single Point is giving the other 2 side lengths.
You should also consider the case when 2 Points are giving the other 2 side lengths. Eg $AX$ & $BY$
This too is trivial , though still necessary.
(3) You should write it out with formal format.
That will add clarity & enable usage in other theorems.
(4) "This also simultaneously that difference between any 2 sides is always lesser than the third side." : Nice work with showing more than what was wanted !
You should write this too with formal format.

I just assumed that it was not necessary to show those other two cases because they would obviously result in a smaller magnitude based just on the diagram. But still thanks a lot for your suggestions

When you move to higher classes , you will come across cases where things work out at exactly $X=Y$ , @Rishwanth , while $X<Y$ not working will require some Proof & $X>Y$ will require some other Proof. We should not assume things , since "obvious" things are sometimes not true !
